# Recenter an image within a particular rectangle

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am making a somewhat naïve version of a chess game using the tkinter module. I have successfully 'drawn' out a board using Canvas and placed the pieces on their starting squares. I have written functions that allow the pieces to move about the board freely, but I have not yet tackled the more complex logic of determining legal moves and other rules of gameplay. Basically, the board consists of 64 'rectangle' objects of alternating colors (like a chessboard), and the pieces have been created as image objects (handled from .png files using PIL).

What I would like to do is that, when a piece is picked up and placed within one of those 64 rectangles, that the piece be automatically centered within the rectangle to whose center it is closest. My idea is to create a function that will reposition the piece on that center coordinate, but I am unsure as how to exactly locate that coordinate with my code. I was thinking I might use the .find_closest() method, but that one does not seem to register rectangles when I click them (but it does register the pieces when clicked on).

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
class Chessboard(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self)
    self.pack()
    self.master.title('Chess')
    self.move_data = {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'piece': None}
    self.draw_board(master)
    self.place_pieces(self.board)

def place_pieces(self,board):
    for r in range (7,5,-1):
        for c in range(8):
            x0 = c*80+24
            y0 = r*80+24
            x1 = c*80+104
            y1 = r*80+104
            center = ((x0+x1)/2, (y0+y1)/2)
            image = pieces[(r,c)][0]
            self.create_piece(center, image, ('piece', pieces[(r,c)][1]))
            self.board.tag_bind(pieces[(r,c)][1], '<ButtonPress-1>', self.choose_piece)
            self.board.tag_bind(pieces[(r,c)][1], '<ButtonRelease-1>', self.release_piece)
            self.board.tag_bind(pieces[(r,c)][1], '<B1-Motion>', self.move_piece)
    for r in range (1,-1,-1):
        for c in range(8):
            x0 = c*80+24
            y0 = r*80+24
            x1 = c*80+104
            y1 = r*80+104
            center = ((x0+x1)/2, (y0+y1)/2)
            image = pieces[(r,c)][0]
            self.create_piece(center, image, ('piece', pieces[(r,c)][1]))
            self.board.tag_bind(pieces[(r,c)][1], '<ButtonPress-1>', self.choose_piece)
            self.board.tag_bind(pieces[(r,c)][1], '<ButtonRelease-1>', self.release_piece)
            self.board.tag_bind(pieces[(r,c)][1], '<B1-Motion>', self.move_piece)

def draw_board(self, master):

    self.board = tk.Canvas(master, width = 680, height = 680, borderwidth = 20)
    self.board.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    for r in range(7, -1, -1):
        for c in range(8):
            if c&1 ^ r&1:
                fill = 'sienna2'

            else:
                fill = 'wheat1'
            x0 = c*80+24
            y0 = r*80+24
            x1 = c*80+104
            y1 = r*80+104
            coords = (x0, y0, x1, y1)
            center = ((x0+x1)/2, (y0+y1)/2)
            sq = files[c] + ranks[-r-1]
            self.board.create_rectangle(coords, fill=fill, width = 0, tags = ('square', sq))


def create_piece(self, coord, image, tags):
    self.board.create_image(coord, image=image, tags = tags)


def choose_piece(self, event):
    self.move_data['piece'] = self.board.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
    self.move_data['x'] = event.x
    self.move_data['y'] = event.y



def release_piece(self, event):


    self.move_data['piece'] = None
    self.move_data['x'] = 0
    self.move_data['y'] = 0



def move_piece(self, event):
    dx = event.x - self.move_data['x']
    dy = event.y - self.move_data['y']
    self.board.move(self.move_data['piece'], dx, dy)
    self.move_data['x'] = event.x
    self.move_data['y'] = event.y
```

Comment: We can't run this code. It has indentation errors, and is missing some global data. Is it possible for you to reduce this down to a [mcve], and preferably one that doesn't depend on external images? _For the purposes of this question_ we don't need a full chess board, we just need a couple squares and one chess piece.

Comment: Read about [Tkinter.Canvas.find_closest-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_closest-method)

Comment: @stovfl: `find_closest` won't work, since it will always find the piece rather than the board that is underneath the piece.

Answer (score 0):

`find_closest` won't work for finding a board square while you're dragging and dropping, since the closest object on the canvas will be the object that you are dragging.

Instead, find the center of the object that is being dragged, and use `find_overlapping` to get a list of all objects that overlap that coordinate. Then, using any algorithm you want, pick one of the items in the returned list. For example, you might always choose the first one, or always the last one. If the board is lower in the stacking order, the last item in the list will be the piece being moved.

Unless you drop lots of overlapping objects on the screen, `find_overlapping` will normally return two items: the item being moved and the square underneath. However, you need to be prepared for the case where the user drops it precisely on the intersection four squares, or the border between two squares.

From there, it's just a bit of math to figure out the center of the square and the center of the object being moved, and then move the object so that they have the same center.

First, define a function to return the center of an object:

```
def _get_center(self, item):
    coords = self.board.coords(item)
    cx = int((coords[2]+coords[0])/2)
    cy = int((coords[3]+coords[1])/2)
    return (cx,cy)
```

Next, define a function to center an object over another object:

```
def align(self, item1, item2):
    x0, y0 = self._get_center(item1)
    x1, y1 = self._get_center(item2)
    deltax = x1 - x0
    deltay = y1 - y0
    self.board.move(item1, deltax, deltay)
```

And finally, in the code that handles the drop, find the objects on the canvas that are overlapping, and then uses that information to align the objects.

In the following example, the code grabs the first item returned by `find_overlapping`. You probably want a better algorithm. For example, you might have a function that returns the possible moves for a piece, and then use the first overlapping item that appears in the list of allowable moves.

```
cx, cy = self._get_center("current")
nearest = self.board.find_overlapping(cx, cy, cx, cy)[0]
self.align("current", nearest)
```

Note: `"current"` is a special canvas tag that refers to the topmost item under the cursor. That should be the thing that you're dragging. In your case you could use `self.move_data['piece']` instead.